# Ripple Effect Duration in Android XML

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, material-design, ripple

I am Learning Material Design. I tried ripple effect on button using this gradle

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
}
```

from this  https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect  link

there are many attribute which are not working
such as

```
app:rv_rippleDuration="1200"
app:rv_color="#d3d3d3"
```

I have event on button and ripple effect but when I click on button method is get called. What I want is first ripple effect should get complete then action should occur.

> XML code

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <com.andexert.library.RippleView
            android:id="@+id/ripple1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            rv_centered="true"
            app:rv_rippleDuration="1800"
            app:rv_color="#000000">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/fromDateButton" />

        </com.andexert.library.RippleView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

user cannot experience animation.

Comment: open an issue on the repo directly. you'll get better responses.

Comment: Instead of adding at XML file, try to add duration in java code.

Comment: Do know how to do that.

Comment: https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect/issues/66 opened issue on git hub

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` as an `xmlns` in your RippleView before using the app resource.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in the example on the page of description in GitHab.
Change

`rv_centered="true"`

to

`app:rv_centered="true"`

and all will be done.
All attribute of ReppleView must contain `app:`

Comment: no it's not working. I think, I should add `thread` to every event to sleep for till ripple effect completes and then release the `thread`