# Reduce ripple effect duration android

Tags: android, ripple

I am using third party library Here's https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect to achieve `ripple effect` and I am successful in that .

I am calling my `action code` inside `setOnRippleCompleteListener`

The problem is it takes a little more time to complete the `ripple effect` , then it fires the `action code`

I used `app:rv_framerate` & `app:rv_rippleDuration` to reduce `ripple effect` time, but didn't found any difference it `ripple effect` speed

Comment: go to library and set ripple effect speed according to your need.

Comment: I am using Android Studio , can u please help me with steps to locate

Comment: Solved this using the post Here's [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251820/ripple-effect-duration-in-android-xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251820/ripple-effect-duration-in-android-xml)